# Meteor. Prevent template re-rendering or disable reactivity

Tags: meteor

I have a template with multiple inputs. And they lag if i fill them quickly, because of the delay between the client and the server.
Is there a way to prevent re-rendering of the current input? Or disable reactivity to the entire template, and re-render it manually?

If I use the `keyup` event the current input is laggy, and if the `change` then the next one.

I heard about `{{#isolate}}` and `{{#constant}}` but I can't find the documentation about it.

Comment: Can you show some basic code? Why is it lagging, what is re-rendering?

Comment: Code is pretty simple. Just an template with many inputs, and publication + subscribe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a `find()` query you can use the `reactive` option to switch it off:

```
YourCollection.find({}, {reactive: false})
```

To disable reactivity.

If you use variables you could use ordinary `var variablename` instead of `Session.get('variableName')` or `ReactiveDict` type variables to disable their reactivity.

`{{#isolate}}` and `{{#constant}}` have been deprecated since the new Blaze engine isolates DOM automatically and no longer requires it to be manually isolated.